# How do I insert a function along with a word in numbers

Tags: macbook-pro, numbers

I am using numbers and I have a column function at the footer row. I'd like it to produce a Countif() along with a word.

I tried: `=Countif(Checkboxes,True) "Checkboxes"`
so that it would express for example `5 Checkboxes`

That did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the custom cell format rather than the function.

1. Go to the cell click format>manage custom cell formats
2. From the Type pop-up menu, choose Number & Text
3. Drag the (blue) Entered Text element from the Date & Time Elements box into the
   empty format field above the box.
4. Place the insertion point after the element, and then type your text 'checkboxes'
5. Click Ok to save.